# From article on Wikipedia, is this a LL(0) grammar?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I am studying LL/LR parses and while reading the [LL parser page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Set_up), I found this grammar:

```
S → F
S → ( S + F )
F → a
```

From the article it is LL (LL(0) I assume from the table); but I found a proof which states that an LL(0) parser has no Left-recursion (in this case with S). So, how comes that this is a proper LL(0) (or at least, this is what I understood from the article).

Is the 'no left-recursion' some sort of general rule or just a flag of a *possible* issue?

And can the parsing table tell me **for sure** whether the grammar I am working on is LL(0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can identify a LL(0) grammar by looking at the parse table, as follows:

1. Every non-terminal is associated with only one right-hand side.
2. There is no use of the EBNF operators `?`, `*`, or `+`.

Many would state an additional rule that recursion is not allowed. However, this is trivially implied by the previous rules due to the fact that *any* recursion would result in an infinite loop.

Your example grammar is not LL(0) because there are 2 productions defined for the non-terminal `s`.

Comment: *S* has two right hand sides. However, we know which one we are looking at just from one symbol, without an additional lookahead.